# How to achieve a blink effect in javafx

Tags: javafx

In Javafx, I know that when set modality of a Stage to APPLICATION_MODAL, it will block events from being delivered to other stage.
Now I want to add a warning effect, just like the Dialog component in Javafx. To be more specific, when I try to click other stage, my stage will blink to warn me that I cannot do that.
So how to achieve that effect? I have no clue.

Comment: What does this “blink effect” look like and do? What part of the stage blinks? You talk about multiple stages, which one blinks?

Comment: @jewelsea Just like the Windows dialogs do. For example, there is a main stage and a dialog stage. You are working on the main stage. When you push some button and the dialog pops up, it will block all events from being delivered to the main stage. And when you try to click the main stage, the whole dialog stage will blink quickly for several times just to tell you that you cannot unfocus it.

Comment: Your host platform may offer a suitable accessibility feature that needs to be enabled.